# Scroll animation with toggling between fixed and absolute position

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, css-animations

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var blocParent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent-bloc");
    var block4 = document.getElementById("block4");
    var block5 = document.getElementById("block5");
    var block6 = document.getElementById("block6");
    var block4Top = block4.offsetTop;
    var block5Top = block5.offsetTop;
    var bloc4Visible = false;
    var bloc5Visible = false;
    var bloc6Visible = false;
    var bloc4TopDefined = false;
    var continueScroll = true;
    var distanceBloc5 = 0;
    var distanceBloc6 = 0;
    scrollTopInitial = false;
    var blocParentPassed = false;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var lastScrollTop1 = 0;

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if (continueScroll) {

            // Bloc 4
            if (scrollPosition >= block4Top && scrollPosition <= (block4Top + window.innerHeight) && scrollPosition > lastScrollTop) {
                if (!bloc4TopDefined) {
                    distanceBloc5 = block4Top + 200;
                    distanceBloc6 = block4Top + 600;
                    bloc4TopDefined = true;
                }
                fixBloc4()

                if (!bloc6Visible) {
                    blocParent[0].style.removeProperty("position");
                    block4.classList.remove("bloc4-absolute");
                    block5.classList.remove("bloc5-absolute");
                    block6.classList.remove("bloc6-absolute");
                }
            } else if (scrollPosition < block4Top && !bloc5Visible) {

                block4.style.removeProperty("position");
                block4.classList.remove("fixed4");

                if (!bloc4TopDefined) {
                    distanceBloc5 = block4Top + 200;
                    distanceBloc6 = block4Top + 600;
                    bloc4TopDefined = true;
                }
                bloc4Visible = false;
            }

            // Bloc 5
            if (bloc4Visible && scrollPosition >= distanceBloc5 && scrollPosition > lastScrollTop) {
                fixBloc5();
            }
            else if (scrollPosition < distanceBloc5 && scrollPosition > block4Top) {
                hideBloc5(150);
            }

            // Bloc 6 
            if (bloc5Visible && scrollPosition >= distanceBloc6 && scrollPosition > lastScrollTop) {
                fixBloc6();

                // If bloc6 is visible and user keep scrolling down
                if (scrollPosition >= distanceBloc6 + 100) {
                    continueScroll = false;                    
                }
            }
            else if (scrollPosition < lastScrollTop && bloc5Visible) {
                hideBloc6(100);
            }
        }

        // !continueScroll
        else {
            if (!scrollTopInitial) {
                lastScrollTop1 = block4Top;
                scrollTopInitial = true;
            }

            if (lastScrollTop1 >= block4Top) {
                if (!blocParentPassed) {
                    blocParent[0].scrollIntoView();
                    blocParentPassed = true;
                }
                else if (scrollPosition > lastScrollTop && scrollPosition >= block4Top && !bloc5Visible && !bloc6Visible) {
                    block4.style.removeProperty("position");
                    fixBloc4();
                    continueScroll = true;
                }
                else {
                    blocParent[0].style.position = "relative";
                    block4.style.position = "absolute";
                    block5.classList.add("bloc5-absolute")
                    block6.style.position = "absolute";
                }

                if (scrollPosition < lastScrollTop) {
                    if (bloc6Visible) {
                        if ((lastScrollTop - lastScrollTop1) < 700) {                            
                            hideBloc6(150);
                        }
                    }
                    if (bloc5Visible && lastScrollTop1 < block5Top) {
                        if ((lastScrollTop - lastScrollTop1) < 700) {
                            hideBloc5(150);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    lastScrollTop1++;
                }
            }
            else {
                lastScrollTop1--;
                //continueScroll = true;
                if (bloc6Visible) {
                    if ((lastScrollTop - lastScrollTop1) < 700) {
                        hideBloc6(150);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollPosition;
    });

    function hideBloc6(distance) {
        block6.style.transform = "translateY(" + distance + "em)";
        block6.style.zIndex = "30";
        bloc6Visible = false;
    }

    function fixBloc4(){
        block4.classList.add("fixed4");
        bloc4Visible = true;
    }

    function fixBloc5() {
        block5.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
        block5.style.zIndex = "20";
        block5.style.position = "fixed";
        block5.style.top = "200px";
        bloc5Visible = true;
    }

    function fixBloc6() {
        block6.style.transform = "translateY(0em)";
        block6.style.zIndex = "30";
        block6.style.position = "fixed";
        block6.style.top = "400px";
        bloc6Visible = true;
    }

    function hideBloc5(distance){
        block5.style.transform = "translateY(" + distance + "em)";
        bloc5Visible = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
    <!-- <script defer src="script.js"></script> -->
    <title>Scroll Animation</title>
</head>

<style>    
    .bloc {
        transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    }

    .content {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }

    .fixed4 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    img{
        width: 55%;
    }
    .bloc5-absolute{
        position: absolute !important;
        top: 13em !important;
    }
    
</style>

<body>
    <br>

    
    <div class="section1">
        <h1>Test SECTION 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p></br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p></br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p></br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="section3">
        <h1>Test SECTION 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p></br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p></br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p></br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
            voluptate
            id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
            pariatur.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-bloc" style="height: 150em;">
        <a href="parent-bloc"></a>
        <div class="bloc" id="block4">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Text for Block 4</p>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/07/17/12/13/bird-8132549_1280.jpg" alt="Image 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bloc invisible animated fade-in" id="block5" style="transform: translateY(100em);">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/07/17/12/13/bird-8132549_1280.jpg" alt="Image 2">
                <p>Text for Block 5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bloc invisible animated fade-in" id="block6" style="transform: translateY(100em);">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Text for Block 6</p>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/07/17/12/13/bird-8132549_1280.jpg" alt="Image 3">
            </div>
            <div class="section2">
                <h1>Test SECTION 2</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
                    voluptate
                    id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
                    pariatur.</p></br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
                    voluptate
                    id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
                    pariatur.</p></br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
                    voluptate
                    id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
                    pariatur.</p></br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero deserunt ipsa ad commodi, sit molestiae
                    voluptate
                    id facere fugit nemo nostrum corporis, necessitatibus mollitia? Veniam molestias modi possimus voluptatum
                    pariatur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        
    </div>
    <!-- Add more blocks as needed -->

    
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    

</body>

</html>
```

I have created html page with a corresponfing js file. I want to add specific animations on this page while scrolling through.

The animation concerns the 3 blocs having class="bloc" that should follow these steps:

On page load, the block5 and block6 are not visible

1- When scrolling down, the bloc having id="block4" stays fixed when it arrives  at the top of the page

2- While keep scrolling, the next block (block5) arrives 200px down from block4 with donw to top animation (translateY) and stays fixed too

3- Same thing for the block6, 200px down from block5

4- When the block6 is in viewport an we keep scrolling down, all those 3 blocks maintain their distance but souhldn't be fixed anymore, so they go up together

5- When scrolling up and the block4 arrives at top of the page, block4 becomes fixed again and the block6 disappears by fading down as we keep scrolling up

6- Then the block5 disappears too by fading down and the block4 looses fixed position

I have tried javascript scroll event listener with scroll position conditions and toggle between fixed and absolute position on each bloc but the behavior is not always the same depending on scroll position. The sticky position in css is a solution but the blocs will appear little by little,yet I want them to show on time like bottom to top. I'm stuck on the 5 and 6 steps so if anyone can help please I would be grateful. Thank you so much !!

Comment: You should include your current JS (you say you are struggling with steps 5 & 6, so you must have coding for the previous steps in place already?); provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for answering, I have provided my complete code so you can reproduce it. I hope it can help you to understand my problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.